# Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation valgrind C

Tags: c

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_PT.UTF-8");
FILE *vocabulario = fopen(*(++argv),"r");
FILE *original = fopen(*(++argv),"r");
FILE *convertido = fopen(*(++argv),"w");
if (vocabulario == NULL || original == NULL || convertido == NULL){
    printf("Não foi possível abrir um dos ficheiros");
    return 1;
}
char delimitador = '\t';
TNode * root = NULL;
Conversor * temp = NULL;
char linhaLida[BUFFER];
char linhaTemp[BUFFER];
char linhaEscrever[BUFFER];
int i = 0;
while(fgets(linhaLida,BUFFER,vocabulario) != NULL){
    if ( !criarConversor(&temp,linhaLida,delimitador) ) continue;
    insertNodeViciado(&root,temp);
    i++;
}

    /* criarConversor implementation*/
20 int criarConversor(Conversor ** temp,char * stringAUsar,char delimitador){
21     int contador = obterNumeroDelimitadores(stringAUsar,delimitador);
22     char delimitadorInterno[] = {delimitador,'\n'};
23     if (contador == 0) return 0;
24     *temp = malloc(sizeof(Conversor));
25     verificarAlocacao(*temp);
26     (*temp)->original = obterStringAlocada(stringAUsar,delimitadorInterno);
27     if (contador == 1){
28         (*temp)->preferencia = obterStringAlocada(NULL,delimitadorInterno);
29         (*temp)->opcoes = NULL;
30     } else {
31         (*temp)->preferencia = NULL;
32         (*temp)->opcoes = malloc((contador+1)*sizeof(char *));
33         verificarAlocacao((*temp)->opcoes);
34         int i = 0;
35         while(i<contador) *(((*temp)->opcoes)+i++) =  obterStringAlocada(NULL,delimitadorInterno);
36        *(((*temp)->opcoes)+i) = NULL;
       }
37     return 1;



typedef struct conversor{
    char * original;
    char * preferencia;
    char ** opcoes;
} Conversor;

Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2306==    at 0x40AB01E: strtok (strtok.S:165)
==2306==    by 0x8048E1E: criarConversor (Conversor.c:35)
==2306==    by 0x8048984: main (main.c:24)
==2306==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2306==    at 0x8048D18: criarConversor (Conversor.c:20)


/*Gets the token,checks to see if there was a token,allocates on the heap and returns the pointer to the heap allocated string*/
char * obterStringAlocada(char * string,char * delimitador){
    char * token = strtok(string,delimitador);
    verificarAlocacao(token);
    char * alocada = strcpy(malloc(strlen(token)+1),token);
    return alocada;
}
/*Counts how many delimiters there is on the string*/
int obterNumeroDelimitadores(char * string,char delimitador){
    int contador = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (*(string+i) != '\0') if (*(string+i++) == delimitador)contador++;
    return contador;
}
/* checks if the memory was properly allocated,which why its always called after   malloc*/
void verificarAlocacao(void * verificar){
    if (verificar == NULL){
        printf("Não foi possível alocar a memória necessária\nO programa vai encerrar");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Valgrind gives me the Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation in the implementation of criarConversor().

My question is: how can the values be uninitialized? delimitador is a set variable as are the others two. I could understand if someone said linhaLida isn't initialized except the code will never reach the if(!criarConversor()) unless linhaLida is written by the fgets function.

Comment: Well, these are all uninitialized: `char linhaLida[BUFFER],linhaTemp[BUFFER],linhaEscrever[BUFFER];` But it will be hard to give an exact answer without a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/http://sscce.org/) of code giving this error.

Comment: I'm not a fan of your formatting, nor the use of sequence points (`,`) in opening files.

Comment: If I add linhaLida[BUFFER] = 0; it still gives me the same error,I've even allocated space for the temp variable and it still gives me the error. Besides linhaLida will be initialized by the fgets function before it even reaches the if,if the fgets returns NULL then the if is unreachable and I thought it wouldn't a concern;

Sorry Fiddling Bits i'll change it now

Comment: I meant add linhaLida[BUFFER] = {0};

I have around 0.5GB of test cases and none have given me this error,only valgrind seems to do it.

Besides if the fgets returns NULL then the if code is unreachable and if fgets doesn't return NULL then linhaLida is initialized and the problem of being uninitialized doesn't exist I think?

Comment: @FiddlingBits the comma separator is not a sequence point

Comment: Can you post the exact messages from valgrind please? "Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation in the implementation of criarConversor()." seems to be your paraphrasing. It should indicate a series of function name, source file name and line number

Comment: I've added the information you requested on the first post.

Comment: The trace shows that the uninitialized read is occurring in `strtok`. (The trace is with most-recent-first).  Is `obterStringAlocada` a `#define` for `strtok`?  (Either way please post the code for `obterStringAlocada` and `obterNumeroDelimitadores` and `verificarAlocacao` and any other non-standard functions they call

Comment: also, which lines are line 20 and line 35?

Comment: I'll add on the original post,i've added a small description on top of them to describe whats their purpose/what they do

Comment: @MattMcNabb `C99, Annex C, Sequence Points`

Comment: @FiddlingBits the comma separator is not mentioned in Annex C. You're mixing it up with the comma operator.  Function arguments are not operands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
char delimitadorInterno[] = {delimitador,'\n'};

// ...

char * token = strtok(string,delimitador);
```

The second argument to `strtok` is supposed to point to a *string* which is the separator to look for . However you passed a pointer to two characters which do not form a string, thereby causing undefined behaviour which valgrind catches when `strtok` reads past the '\n'.

To fix this, change to:

```
char delimitadorInterno[] = { delimitador,'\n', 0 };
```

or perhaps

```
char delimitadorInterno[] = { delimitador, 0 };
```

I guess you are intending to use just the delimiter character as separator (as opposed to the sequence of the delimiter followed by a newline). Since the result of `fgets` can only have a newline at the end, then the version with `\n` will never match anything unless the line ends in delimiter , in which case it will match once.

Comment: I had that before and removed it -.- .

Anyway thanks a lot for the time spent on this.